# Add column to recordset adodb connection in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that consolidates data from multiple closed workbooks and the code is OK. My question is how to add a column to the recordset so as to put the file name (the source where the data come from)
Here's my code

```
Sub Test()
    Dim e, cn As Object, rs As Object, myPath As String, fn As String, i As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        shTotal.Cells.ClearContents
        myPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\xls\"
        fn = Dir(myPath & "*.xls?")
        Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        f = True
        Do Until fn = ""
            cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & myPath & fn & ";" & "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';"
            cn.Open
            rs.Open Source:="SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", ActiveConnection:=cn
            shTotal.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs
            rs.Close: cn.Close
            fn = Dir
        Loop
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I tried Rory's suggestion but I didn't get any data

```
    'Dim a
    'a = rs.GetRows()
    shTotal.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs
    'shTotal.Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(a, 1)).Value = Split(fn, ".")(0)
```

Comment: You don't need to add it to the recordset - just populate the adjacent cells in your code. Also, Power Query would be as easy really.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried your suggestion but I didn't get any data. Can you please have a look at the update?

Comment: If you use `GetRows`, you'll need to use `rs.MoveFirst` to go back to the start of the recordset before copying it. Also, the array is transposed, so for the right number of rows, you want the `Ubound` of the **second** dimension.

Comment: Is there another way to know the number of rows without using GetRow() method?

Comment: Yes, you can use the same `End(xlUp).Row` method to get the new last populated row.